# How to convert complex json string with nested objects to map in golang?

Tags: dictionary, go

I have a complex string in json format which i want to convert to a map in golang. Let's say the string is

```
      species :{
               "type" : "human"
               "age" : "23"
               "attributes" : {
                              "height" : "182"
                              "weight" : "160"
                              "contact" : {
                                          "address" : ########
                                          "phone" : #########
                              }
               }
      }
```

how do i parse it such that map[attributes] is a again a map[string]interface and so on ?

Comment: Take a look at how encoding/json does it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map[string]interface{}, for example:

```
species := make(map[string]interface{})
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &species); err != nil {
   // deal with error
}
```